# smtp_error: couldn't connect to server

Tags: php, openssl, phpmailer

i've following code

```
 phpinfo();

       $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->Port = 465;


            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->Username= 'someone@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password='xxx';
            $mail->From  = "someone@gmail.com";
            $mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com");

            $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
            $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo 'Message was not sent.';
          echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          echo 'Message has been sent.';
        }
```

i also enable "extension=php_openssl.dll" in php.ini file..

but still its giving me an error ,

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

though i have `extension=php_openssl.dll` enabled in my php.ini file, phpinfo(); shows that `OpenSSL support:disabled (install ext/openssl)`.how it is possible?

can anyone help??

Comment: similar one, does this help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813048/error-unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl-with-zend-mail

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

I had problems with this one. Check if your PHPMailer version is up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

It means that either your ssl module didn't compile properly or it was compiled but its not enabled via the php.ini configuration file.

Check your settings to make sure you have it enabled.

Comment: Sorry but didn't get u exactly.what do u mean by 'ssl module dont complile'??

Comment: i have enabled extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

try below example:

http://www.xtreemhost.com/2010/04/11/how-to-send-e-mails-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/